# how I can get specific text with regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to get all text that appear in this format

```
/anyword/specific_word/any number 0-9
```

#### Attempt

```
Regex rx = new Regex(@"[0-9]{19}",
                  RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Provide clear examples of the text and the matches required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that any word would only have `[A-Za-z]` chars, we can likely start with this expression:

```
/[A-Za-z]+/specific_word/[0-9]+
```

which we can add other chars to this class, `[A-Za-z]`, if desired.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/h8Tm8r/2/)

#### Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"/[A-Za-z]+/specific_word/[0-9]+";
        string input = @"/anyword/specific_word/012345
/anyword1/specific_word/012345
/anyword/specific_word_0/012345";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
        
        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `/` is not a special regex metacharacter, do not escape it in string patterns.

Comment: Your solution is not flexible 'cause I guess OP has *several* specific words, so you need an alternate construction.